# Подключить Paging Library к RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть приложение - словарь, которое выводит один из списков из БД в зависимости от условия с русского на английский и наоборот. Реализовано через `LiveData` и `ViewModel`. Как подключить к `RecyclerView` `Paging Library`? Пыталась сделать как описано тут https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging, но с двумя списками получилась путаница в итоге все удалила.

Класс RusOther:

```
public class RusOther {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) //Система сама будет инкрементировать это поле в БД
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String word;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String translation;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int favorites;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    public int getFavorites() {
        return favorites;
    }

    public void setFavorites(int favorites) {
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }

    public RusOther(int id, String word, String translation, int favorites) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
        this.translation = translation;
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }
}
```

Класс OtherRus:

```
public class OtherRus {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) //Система сама будет инкрементировать это поле в БД
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String word;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String translation;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int favorites;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    public int getFavorites() {
        return favorites;
    }

    public void setFavorites(int favorites) {
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }

    public OtherRus(int id, String word, String translation, int favorites) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
        this.translation = translation;
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }
}
```

Адаптер RusOtherAdapter

```
public class RusOtherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RusOtherAdapter.WordViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<RusOther> mWords;
    private List<RusOther> mFilteredList;
    private Context mContext;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final TextView txtWord;

        private WordViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtWord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public RusOtherAdapter(Context context, List<RusOther> mWords) {
        this.mWords = mWords;
        this.mFilteredList = mWords;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        WordViewHolder vh = new WordViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final RusOther word = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.txtWord.setText(word.getWord());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = mWords;
                } else {

                    List<RusOther> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (RusOther word : mWords) {

                        if (word.getWord().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(word);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (List<RusOther>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Адаптер OtherRusAdapter

```
public class OtherRusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OtherRusAdapter.WordViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<OtherRus> mWords;
    private List<OtherRus> mFilteredList;
    private Context mContext;

    RusOtherAdapter.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final RusOtherAdapter.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final TextView txtWord;

        private WordViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtWord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public OtherRusAdapter(Context context, List<OtherRus> mWords) {
        this.mWords = mWords;
        this.mFilteredList = mWords;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        WordViewHolder vh = new WordViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final OtherRus word = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.txtWord.setText(word.getWord());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = mWords;
                } else {

                    List<OtherRus> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (OtherRus word : mWords) {

                        if (word.getWord().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(word);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (List<OtherRus>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface RusOtherDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM rusother")
    LiveData<List<RusOther>> getAllRusOtherWords(); //Через LiveData мы наблюдаем за списком и обновляем его при изменениях

    @Query("SELECT * FROM rusotherWHERE id = :id")
    RusOther getRusOtherByID(long id);
}

@Dao
public interface OtherRusDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM otherrus")
    LiveData<List<OtherRus>> getAllOtherRusWords(); //Через LiveData мы наблюдаем за списком и обновляем его при изменениях

    @Query("SELECT * FROM otherrusWHERE id = :id")
    OtherRus getOtherRusByID(long id);
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class AppViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private AppDatabase appDataBase;

    public AppViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        appDataBase = AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(this.getApplication());
    }

    //Получение всех слов с русского на другой язык
    public LiveData<List<RusOther>> getAllRusOtherWords(){
        return appDataBase.rusOtherDao().getAllRusOtherWords();
    }

    //Получение всех слов с другого на русский язык
    public LiveData<List<OtherRus>> getAllOtherRusWords(){
        return appDataBase.otherRusDao().getAllOtherRusWords();
    }

    public RusOther getByRusOtherId(long id){
        return appDataBase.rusOtherDao().getRusOtherByID(id);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, RusOtherAdapter.OnItemClickListener, OtherRusAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private AppViewModel viewModel;

    private RecyclerView rvList;
    RusOtherAdapter rusOtherAdapter;
    OtherRusAdapter otherRusAdapter;

    private TextView txtLeftLang;
    private TextView txtRightLang;
    private ImageButton btnChangeLang;
    private boolean isOtherRight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ***

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppViewModel.class);

        viewModel.getAllRusOtherWords().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<RusOther>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<RusOther> words) {
                for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(words.get(i).getWord());
                }
                rusOtherAdapter = new RusOtherAdapter(MainActivity.this, words);
                rusOtherAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                rvList.setAdapter(rusOtherAdapter);
            }
        });

        btnChangeLang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                txtRightLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang));
                txtLeftLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang));

                if (isOtherRight) { //перевод с русского на другой
                    rvList.setAdapter(null);
                    viewModel.getAllRusOtherWords().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<RusOther>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<RusOther> words) {
                            rusOtherAdapter = new RusOtherAdapter(MainActivity.this, words);
                            rusOtherAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                            rvList.setAdapter(rusOtherAdapter);
                        }
                    });
                } else { // перевод с другого на русский
                    rvList.setAdapter(null);
                    viewModel.getAllOtherRusWords().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<OtherRus>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<OtherRus> words) {
                            otherRusAdapter = new OtherRusAdapter(MainActivity.this, words);
                            otherRusAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                            rvList.setAdapter(otherRusAdapter);
                        }
                    });
                }

                isOtherRight = !isOtherRight;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override //Нажатие на элемент списка
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, id + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
        search(searchView);
        return true;
    }

    public void search(SearchView searchView) {

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                //if (adapter != null) adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: эта либа конечно ооочень интересная и я был рад у себя ее юзать, но так и не смог ее внедрить у себя в приложение, поэтому пилил свой аналог, который работает тоже нормально :)

Comment: Сам недавно внедрял Pagging в свой проект где MVVM,  можете посмотреть по ссыдкам : https://github.com/Vennic/VMPlayerV2/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/kuzheevadel/vmplayerv2/paging,  https://github.com/Vennic/VMPlayerV2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kuzheevadel/vmplayerv2/fragments/SearchRadioFragment.kt,  https://github.com/Vennic/VMPlayerV2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kuzheevadel/vmplayerv2/viewmodels/SearchRadioViewModel.kt